# Having a odd issue with CSS3PIE in IE7/8

Tags: internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, css3pie

Lately I installed CSS3PIE and have enabled it. It is indeed working. However, in IE7/8 I am seeing some odd behavior when CSS3PIE is on a modal window.

For example, here is a modal loaded with CSSPIE elements on it in IE7/8:
http://d.pr/i/p17h

You see, no elements show up. When I simple hover over where one should be, I see this:
http://d.pr/i/CKM0

Basically, they render correctly once hovered.  For the modal, I am using Lightbox_Me.

***Any suggestions?!***

Comment: Take a look at the [CSS3Pie known issues page](http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/). It could well be the IE `hasLayout` bug, in which case adding `zoom:1` to your CSS for the element may resolve it.

Comment: also tried this, wouldnt work. this only happens on modals unfortunately.